# .Net Design Architecture Scalable

Tags: asp.net, scalability, session-state, database-performance

We currently have a system that has somewhat over 200,000 unique session request/day and so we have introduce a new server with a load balancer to handle the load. This is where the problem comes in because Our sessionstate ="InProcess". Once a user initiates the application, we load a  some important variables in the Session because these variables are used throughout the application and instead of hitting the database every page we store it in a Session Object. Which works but using this way we have to make sure the App Pool doesn't recycle but once a day and during downtime hours which make the server memory get huge throughout the day. Keep in mind that this system is initiated from System A, so if these main values are lost then the application has to be reopened by System A

Solution 1: Replace using the Session Object for storing variables to an Application Cache (But will this be able to retain their values during App Pool recycle)

Solution 2: Hit the SQL server database every page for these values ( But I think this will not scale well to continually open and close connections for information I could maintain in the application)

Solution 3: update Session Objects used to be serialize and add a StateServer in the mix to handle the session being retained during App Pool recycle and across both servers (but doesn't this bring performance down).

Solution 4: Save these values to the client side of the code by using hidden controls and send those values to the server every hit. These properties are not sensitive information so this should not be a problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution 1: If you use built-in .NET cache, it does not survive the app pool recycle.

Solution 2: I wouldn't recommend that however you can write your own session storage provider and use any key-value storage (e.g. filesystem or maybe some document database). But you are de facto writing your own State Server.

Solution 3: State Server is fine for small number of instances. It is also reasonably fast so I would prefer it.

Solution 4: If the information is large to be stored in a cookie (there is 4kB limit I think), you can use hidden form fields but it is not an elegant solution. It is usable only if we are talking about several variables you need to persist.

I don't know the application however for most cases I would pick the State Server.